# Get Identity Token on Manual Implicit flow login (IdentityServer4)

Tags: openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have setup an identity server 4. I have setup a client using the followed the manual sample [here.](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/MvcManual) Here is the code.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Contact()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return View();

            return await StartAuthentication();
        }

        private async Task<IActionResult> StartAuthentication()
        {
            // read discovery document to find authorize endpoint
            var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");

            var authorizeUrl = new RequestUrl(disco.AuthorizeEndpoint).CreateAuthorizeUrl(
                clientId: "mvc",
                responseType: "id_token",
                scope: "openid profile",
                redirectUri: "http://localhost:5002/home/callback",
                state: "random_state",
                nonce: "random_nonce",
                responseMode: "form_post");

            return Redirect(authorizeUrl);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
        {
            var state = Request.Form["state"].FirstOrDefault();
            var idToken = Request.Form["id_token"].FirstOrDefault();
            var error = Request.Form["error"].FirstOrDefault();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) throw new Exception(error);
            if (!string.Equals(state, "random_state")) throw new Exception("invalid state");

            var user = await ValidateIdentityToken(idToken);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user);
            return Redirect("/home/contact");
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            //await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            //var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");

            //return Redirect(disco.EndSessionEndpoint);

            var idToken = (await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "id_token"));
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
            var endSessionUrl = new RequestUrl(disco.EndSessionEndpoint).CreateEndSessionUrl(
                    postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc",
                    idTokenHint: idToken

                );

            return Redirect(endSessionUrl);
        }
```

Currently

```
var idToken = (await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "id_token"));
```

is null.

If I change the code to have

```
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Contact()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return View();

            return await StartAuthentication();
        }
```

It basically skips the manual method and automatically redirects based on the configuration in the startup. **Then the value IS NOT NULL**

I have also tried:

```
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user, new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            [OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken] = idToken
        }));
```

with no luck.

The startup code looks like the following:

```
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

How do I set and get the identity token when manually triggering the signing as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this piece of code

```
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
            var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
            tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken, Value = idToken });
            authenticationProperties.StoreTokens(tokens);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user, authenticationProperties);
```

After reading through the asp.net security code I found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/8654efeb4da54e7f05dbce38ecdbcd8c540d8388/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs)

Seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit flow returns token as fragment, not as query parameters. You could include response_mode=form_post in request parameter to force OP to return token as form post parameter if OP supports Form Post Response Mode, http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html.